# ARKit takes 30 seconds to start tracking?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, arkit

Ok, exploring ARKit with Swift in iOS 11 here and I have made a very simple app that just adds nodes at the point where the user taps:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene
        let actualScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
        guard let hitFeature = results.last else { return }
        let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4.init(hitFeature.worldTransform) // <- if higher than beta 1, use just this -> hitFeature.worldTransform

        let hitPosition = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41,
                                         hitTransform.m42,
                                         hitTransform.m43)

        createBall(hitPosition: hitPosition)
    }
func createBall(hitPosition : SCNVector3) {
        let newBall = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
        let newBallNode = SCNNode(geometry: newBall)
        newBallNode.position = hitPosition
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newBallNode)
    }
```

And this works. My issue is that when first running the app, it takes 30-60 seconds of just panning the camera around where tapping does nothing.

It seems like ARKit is "loading", so that when I tap in this first minute no nodes appear in the tapped position. Nothing happens for that first minute.

Why is this? Is there a way to expedite this loading process? What is happening here?

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem, but my solution, at least whilst thinking of the user, was to present an activity indicator until the AR was ready to start interactions. I essentially just had a timer fire a method that attempted to do a ARHitTest on the AR Scene from the center position of the screen. Once the touch actually returned an array that wasn't empty, I would remove the AR. I'm not sure of a way to make this process quicker aside from just moving the camera around so that the tracking can get more information.

Answer (score 0):

On the overrided function viewWillAppear call this function

```
func setUpSceneView() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

        sceneView.session.run(configuration)

        sceneView.delegate = self
    }
```

and delete everything in viewdidload and add what you need in view will appear